# Yii CDBCriteria - sql - As statement

Tags: yii

How can I use this query in CDBCriteria Format >>

```
SET @orig_lat=122.4058;

SET @orig_lon=37.7907;

SET @dist=10;

SELECT *
     , 3956 
     * 2 
     * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((@orig_lat - abs(dest.latitude)) * pi()/180 / 2),2) + COS(@orig_lat * pi()/180) * COS(ABS (dest.latitude) * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((dest.longitude - @orig_lon) * pi()/180 / 2), 2))) distance
  FROM business 
HAVING distance < @dist
 ORDER 
    BY distance 
 LIMIT 10;
```

Someone asked it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9259232/using-sql-as-statement-in-yii-cdbcriteria).
but I don't get my answer.

Comment: Can you give some context to your question? What do you have and what result do you need? Maybe someone can offer an alternative way.

Answer (score 0):

Consider putting that "Haversine" formula into a MySQL function to start with:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `HAVERSINE`(origin_lat FLOAT, origin_long FLOAT, dest_lat FLOAT, dest_long FLOAT) 
RETURNS float 
DETERMINISTIC 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE R FLOAT;
    SET R = 3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((origin_lat - dest_lat) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) + COS(origin_lat * pi()/180) * COS(dest_lat * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((origin_long-dest_long) * pi()/180 / 2), 2))) * 1.609344; 
    RETURN R; 
END;
```

That way you can call it in your queries.

And then you can abstract further by creating a stored procedure to get the nearest businesses. Something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `findClosestBusinessesToLatLng`(lat FLOAT, lng FLOAT)
BEGIN
    SELECT   *, HAVERSINE(lat, lng, businesses.lat, businesses.lng) AS dist
    FROM     businesses
    ORDER BY dist
END
```

Then your query just becomes

```
Call(findClosestBusinessesToLatLng(122.4058,37.7907));
```

Comment: thank you for answers, and parden me for asking question in a bad way...
but is there anyway to use CDBCriteria in the method?

Comment: @user1710202 What's your aim in using CDBCriteria? If you just want an array of ActiveRecord models why not use the above in a model::findAllBySql() method.